# std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>& Cannot convert parameter

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair

I'm new to `std::map`, started using it only recently.

I'm facing a compilation issue with one of these mappings.

I have a custom structure, and am trying to create a mapping of a `CString`, with objects of that structure type.

Unfortunately, I'm facing issues

`Error  3   error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ItemInfo *' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'`

`ItemInfo` is the structure, to which I'm trying to define a mapping using a `CString`.

This is how I define the mapping..

```
   struct ItemInfo
   {<some code>}

   class XXXX
   {
      std::map<CString, ItemInfo> myMap;
   }
```

I'm not sure how exactly to solve this, or what I should be looking at.

If someone could tell me what this error is, and how I can solve it, it would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

OK - I searched a lot, but still couldn't see the error in my `insert()` function. This is what I use:

```
mAlarmListMpa.insert(tempIterator /*the iterator over the map */, std::pair<CString, ItemInfo>(tagname , info));
```

**EDIT**
Bit more information from the Output :

`

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(208): error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ItemInfo' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'
>   1>          with
>   1>          [
>   1>              _Ty1=const CString,
>   1>              _Ty2=ItemInfo
>   1>          ]
>   1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'ItemInfo' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>'
>   1>          with
>   1>          [
>   1>              _Ty1=const CString,
>   1>              _Ty2=ItemInfo
>   1>          ]
>   1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   `

Comment: It would help if you posted the line that is generating the error.

Comment: I think you are not inserting into the map properly. Anyway, post the code.

Comment: Show us the line that caused the error.

Comment: That's still not the line which causes the error, that's the line which detects the error.

Answer (score 4):

Some code you're not showing us is trying to pass a pointer to `ItemInfo` where it should be passing a key-value pair, presumably `std::pair<CString, ItemInfo>`. The full error message should show you which line of code is doing that.

Comment: Quite probably this is a call of `myMap.insert( )`, which is the usual way to insert a key-value pair.

Comment: I've added the ``insert()` code in the Edit above. If you could have a look at it, please.